# Acessar itens de uma tupla com for (Python)

Tags: python, tupla

Estou rodando o código pelo número de elementos da tupla, porém ele apenas roda o for 2 vezes e para, qual seria o erro?

t1 = ('Doce', 2.3, 'Bala', 0.15, 'Pizza', 28.9, 'Arroz', 4.5, 'Paçoca', 0.5, 'Pamonha', 5.4)
soma = 0
print(len(t1))
for i in (0,len(t1)):
n = input('Qual item você quer pedir? ')
indice = t1.index(n)
soma += t1[indice+1]
print(soma)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Primeiro, como Python é uma linguagem que usa a indentação para definir blocos de código, nas próximas vezes que você postar seria bom você postar como o bloco de código mesmo, pra que a gente consiga identificar a indentação correta.

Pulando para a resposta da sua pergunta, trocando `for i in (0,len(t1)):` por `for i in range(len(t1)):` seu problema deve estar resolvido.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta consegui fazer funcionar com for i in t1. Agora copiei o código diretamente do Google Colab e estava identado,, porém quando foi publicado veio dessa forma desconfigurada.